# Resque_mailer undefined method 'perform' for mailer class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'am trying to send email using Resque and the [Resque_mailer](https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer/) gem, but the sending email jobs are failing after they are queued. I have googled, stackoverflowed, and tested many different code implementations and nothing has worked so far.

I have the following implementation:

Versions: 
    rails (3.2.6)
    resque (1.21.0)
    resque_mailer (2.1.0)

Controller code:

```
def send_newsletter 
  User.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 1000) do |users| 
     users.each { |user| AdminMailer.newsletter(user.email).deliver } 
  end 
end
```

Mailer code:

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
     include Resque::Mailer 

  def newsletter(user_email) 
   mail(:to => user_email, :subject => "New Feature", :from => "noreply@example.com") 
  end

end
```

The jobs are getting queued (I can see them in the web interface in the mailer queue), but are failing. Here is the failing error message:

```
Exception: NoMethodError 
Error: undefined method `perform' for AdminMailer:Class
```

This is strange because in my local development machine the jobs are getting completed without errors. Is there something I am missing to get it to work in production with engineyard?

I have run other resque jobs that do not include sending email or using resque_email just fine.

I would really appreciate any kind of help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue:

The issue was that in production, the Resque processes were not restarting correctly when I deployed my app to EngineYard.

EngineYard has deployment hooks where you can run code at certain points during the deployment process.

In the `after_symlink` deployment hook, the correct code to run is: `sudo "monit restart all -g app_name_resque"`. Where `app_name` is the name of your app. Also, in the `before_restart` deploy hook you need to run: `run "sudo monit start all -g fractalresque_resque"`

This fixed the issue for me!